# Order by a content object's value in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am looking for an elegant way to order a queryset by a specific content object's field.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_pk       = models.TextField('object ID')
    content_object  = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_pk')
```

My content objects are various, but all of them have a 'counter' field

```
class OtherObject(models.Model):
    ...
    counter = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

It would be nice I could query all my MyModel objects ordering them by the related object's counter value.

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't going to be an elegant way to do this in the queryset. To do the sorting in SQL, you would have to join the `MyModel` table to every other table that `content_type` refers to.

You can sort in python, but note this requires one lookup per object.

```
queryset = list(MyModel.objects.all())
sorted_queryset = sorted(queryset, key=lambda x: x.content_object.counter)
```

If sorting on the counter field efficiently is really important to you, you may want to consider moving the counter field (or duplicating it) to `MyModel`.

Comment: I currently make a lookup for each object by a similar method of yours. I would like to move the counter field in MyModel, but "MyModel" makes part of a third party Django app. I think that I will finish by forking the app and adding my field inside. For the mass of objects that I'm dealing with the sorted method takes about a minute. Otherwise it appears that making joins could be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your Model you can define an inner Meta class and define your ordering.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['counter']
```

Would have to test it, but I think that is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, but counter in inside each related object, but not in MyModel class

Comment: Unfortunately not because content_object is not a sql field and Django doesn't recognize it

Comment: The most easy way to go when you have a one-to-many and just want the 'first' from the many and sort it that way.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `order_by` attribute after select your object.

```
Mymodels.objects.all().order_by('name_field')
```

references : https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/asc_or_desc.html